# Unmark My Site deletion from SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, mysite

We have an issue as follows:
In SharePoint 2013 on-premise environment, due to sync problem active users my-sites were marked for deletion. We found it by active users managers got an notification email regarding my site deletion.

We have all users my sites list which are marked as deletion.

How to unmark these mysites or how to stop deletion of these users mysites without stopping 'My Sites Clean UP Timer Job'.

Thanks in Advance, for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Except disabling the timer job “MySite Cleanup job” to avoid any accidental My Site Deletion, there is no way to unmark them.

Do Not directly edit the database table content which is not supported by Microsoft.

[Unmark MySite for deletion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0bf36346-8353-4dfd-97c6-dd2826161fa9/unmark-mysite-for-deletion?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)
[MySite Delete Warning Resolution](https://www.netwoven.com/2014/01/07/mysite-delete-warning-resolution/)